# How to change the QFIELD Icon?

Tags: qfield

I have recently modified QFIELD into a fit for purpose mobile mapping solution for rural address assignment initiative. Now I need to change the QFIELD icon to reflect our organizational identity and to host the environment internally and locally for confidentiality purposes.

I had successfully downloaded the code on github but Android Studio cannot compile that code. It is giving some errors messages referring to the code itself. I also tried to import the code as an eclipse project and that has failed too.

How can I get it right?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.